# Error performing ng build --prod = true --optimization = true in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular7

When I try to execute the following ng build command --prod = true --optimization = true or execute ng build command --prod = true, I have the following error:

```
ERROR in : Error: Illegal State: literal arrays should have been converted into functions
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitLiteralArray (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7338:19)
    at LiteralArray.visit (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:6433:28)
    at _AstToIrVisitor._visit (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7445:52)
    at _AstToIrVisitor.visitConditional (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7287:120)
    at Conditional.visit (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:6320:28)
    at convertPropertyBinding (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:7143:52)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.convertPropertyBinding (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14371:44)
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14174:35
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14331:71
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13787:86
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13787:56)
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:14245:60
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13762:81
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at TemplateDefinitionBuilder.buildTemplateFunction (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:13762:37)
    at compileComponentFromMetadata (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15097:58)
    at compileComponentFromRender2 (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:15183:19)
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23990:21
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler._compilePartialModule (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23966:24)
    at /mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23948:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at AotCompiler.emitAllPartialModules (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:23948:19)
    at AngularCompilerProgram._emitRender3 (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:211:43)
    at AngularCompilerProgram.emit (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/transformers/program.js:200:59)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._emit (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:873:49)
    at AngularCompilerPlugin._update (/mnt/98d9abc7-78bd-4fe3-b361-0111a5393954/git/venta-generica-fe/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js:676:50)
```

If I run ng build, I have no problems
the problem starts when i add --prod = true or - prod and --optimization = true

Comment: You can bypass this error by setting your tsconfig.json to disable Ivy:

"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": false
}